# Excluding a file from git repository permamnently

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

Me & my friend working on the same project and we use VisualStudio TeamServices.
he mistakenly added a huge ".rar" file by his last commit. Now I'm unable to sync my solution because it takes a long time to sync my project. After failing to sync, VisualStudio print the following error:

> Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
>   early EOF.
>   the remote end hung up unexpectedly.
>   index-pack failed

Although he deleted the aforementioned file by another commit, still I can't sync the solution.
Is there any way to get rid of this file, so that VisualStudio won't wait for investigating that file anymore?
I've read some notes about "--rm cached" command, but I think It will be effective for future attempts and it wouldn't help mu current problem to sync my project right now (without checking that ".rar" file).

P.s: Unfortunately I'm a bit newbie to git and it's related concepts (I've never used ). Any detailed answer would be a great help!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository and https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo.

Comment: @ElipieKay thank you, I checked the link you've just suggested, but I'm unfamiliar with git commands :(
can I fix it from GUI in the VisualStudio environment?

Comment: No, I'm afraid you can't. GUI has limited git features. `git filter-branch` is a low-level command.